# amazon/dynamodb-local Error: "Invalid directory for database creation"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

While attempting to run this docker command `docker run -p 8001:8001 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath $DATA_DIRECTORY -cors http://localhost:5173,http://localhost:3000`

I receive a **Invalid directory for database creation.** error. I run the command above from a bash script:

```bash
DATA_DIRECTORY=$(realpath data)
docker run -p 8001:8001 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath $DATA_DIRECTORY -cors http://localhost:5173,http://localhost:3000
```

When I inspect the docker container I can see that the args passed are correct and the folder does exist. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.
[image: image of command args]

Comment: Have you try to use docker argument "-v" with path to volume your want to share (and write) ?